# string array index value :: string issue

Tags: if-statement

I need some help getting the if statement to verify that the string Array index and a string comparison are equal.

```
if((!dclineArr[i].equals("thousand")) || (!dclineArr[i].equals("hundred")))
```

i have also tired

```
if((dclineArr[i] != "thousand") || (dclineArr[i] != "hundred"))
```

everything that goes threw this comparison ends up being true

thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT OR NOT is always true - you need an AND instead of an OR (||)

Your if() checks, if `dclineArr[i]` is not "thousand". If it is "thousand", it checks if it's not "hundred". It cant be both at the same time, so it results in true.

Comment: PERFECT!! why and &&, when logiclly i would want to use an or ||.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that you need to give a bit more detail; in particular, what language are you talking about?

However, it looks like Java, so I'll proceed on the assumption that it is.

As @Katai has already said, your first if statement will always be true.  You're saying, 'if something does not equal "thousand" or that same thing does not equal "hundred", then proceed.'  Can you think of a string for which that is not true?

Your second attempt is one of the classic Java mistakes (we've all done it): using the equals operator to compare objects.  That will only be true if you're comparing two references to the same object.  In this case, of course, you're using not-equals, so the condition will be true for any object that is not the same object as the other one.